# Find out when all content has really finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a reliable cross-browser solution to find out when **all** content on the website has finished loading? As I have a lot of stuff to load (some of which is in iframes), this doesn't really work (the event is fired even though browser's loading indicator is still spinning):

```
$(window).add('iframe').bind('load').promise().done(function() {
    alert('Too early :(');
});
```

Comment: May you can do `$($('#myIframe')[0].contentWindow).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: You can put onload or document.ready handlers in each iframe and have them call a function on the parent window so that the parent can keep track of which ones are loaded and then do something when they all are. It gets fiddly if one of the iframes needs to wait for one of the other iframes since you don't know which'll finish loading first, but if they're all independent and only the parent cares when they're all loaded that's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

i am actually using this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // loading done, now perform for example animate/remove loader icon.
});
```

you can read more about it here:
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

there is also a warning:

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:
>
> It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
>      It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
>      It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
>      Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

i am using it on modern browsers, on both mac/win and did't find any problems so far

Comment: So in other words, there is bullet-proof way to do this?

Comment: not quite…  
**It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser** ;)

Comment: Damn, I meant there is **NO** bullet-proof way to do this :D

Answer (score 0):

Inside the iframe just use and make the function in the toplevel page.

```
$(function(){
    parent.function();
});
```